# Copy of huge data from one collection to another collection in Mongodb using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

We are writing a scheduler to take backup of data from one collection to another collection in Mongodb using spring boot.
The data can be 500K to 1Million docs.
Once the copy was completed we should delete the data from old collection. Currently we are using spring data pagination to get the chunks of data and saving to new collection and then deleting.

Is this approach fine or any optimistic approach is suggestible.

Comment: Consider to rename the collection, would be much faster than copy and delete. And instead of deleting documents, consider to [drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) entire collection which is also much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As you using spring data with pagination for this task, it means you utilizing container for process documents.

You can trigger set of system command(mongo export and after import delete data from source) from scheduler.

Example like..

> SystemCommandTasklet tasklet = new SystemCommandTasklet();
>
> tasklet.setCommand("");
> tasklet.setWorkingDirectory("/home/merlin");